# What happens when we point nil to sprite node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

```
@interface Player()
@property (nonatomic) SKTextureAtlas *atlas;
@end
@implementation Player{
    DecorativeBall *decorativeBall; 
    GolfBall *golfBall; 
}
- (id) initWithBallName :(NSString *) name{
    if(self = [super init]){
        _atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Balls"];
        [self removeAllChildren];
        if ([name isEqualToString:@"DecorativeBall"]) // if it is a decorative ball{
            if (debug){
                printf("\n\n It's a Decorative ball");
            }
            if (!decorativeBall){
                 decorativeBall = [[DecorativeBall alloc] initWithTexture:[_atlas textureNamed:@"DecorativeBall"]];
                golfBall = nil;
            }
            [self addChild:decorativeBall];
        }
        if ([name isEqualToString:@"GolfBall"]) // if it is a golf ball{
            if (debug){
                printf("\n\n It's a Golf ball");
            }
            if (!golfBall){
                golfBall = [[GolfBall alloc] initWithTexture:[_atlas textureNamed:@"GolfBall"]];
                decorativeBall = nil;
            }
            [self addChild:golfBall];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

From the above code decorativeBall = nil and golfBall = nil , does it helps in freeing up the memory or does it make any-sense? 
What I'm trying to do is that , if there is golf ball already selected and now if player has switch it to decorative ball . I want remove golf ball from the scene , is this a correct approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming both `DecorativeBall` and `GolfBall` are subclasses of `SKSpriteNode` and that you're using ARC.

Due to ARC, `golfBall = nil;` does release the sprite but that's not enough, there's still at least one other reference to it: you first need to remove it from the hierarchy by calling `[golfBall removeFromParent];`. The same is true for `decorativeBall`, of course.